# Error status 500 Ajax on Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Good I am trying to delete through ajax but I get the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

I searched the error and apparently appears by the token so I have done what they recommended, I added in the view this:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

**ajax:**

```
$('#delete').on('click', function(){
    var x = $(this);
    var delete_url = x.attr('data-href')+'/'+x.attr('data-id');

    $.ajax({
        url: delete_url,
        type:'DELETE',
        headers:{
            "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        success:function(result){
            alert('success');
        },
        error:function(result){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

**controller:**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $appointment = Appointment::find($id);

    if(appointment == null) {
        return Response()->json([
            'message'=>'error delete.'
        ]);
    }

    $appointment->delete();

    return Response()->json([
        'message'=>'sucess delete.'
    ]);
}
```

**route:**

```
Route::name('appointments.destroy')->delete('/citas/{id}', 'AppointmentController@destroy');
```

it is certainly a token error because if I do not need it on the route it does it perfectly ...

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'citas/*'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the route in the web.php file?

Comment: done! @mbozwood

Comment: Your delete URL is perfect ??

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of `console.log(delete_url);`

Comment: why dont you use axios.. laravel comes with axios.. more simplified ajax with csrf token

Comment: @linktoahref done!

Comment: try `Route::name('appointments.destroy')->delete('citas/{id}' , 'AppointmentController@destroy');` Please check your network tab for more detailed error message

Comment: @linktoahref Thanks for your answer, I already modify it, still it is still not resolved ... I do not know what else I can do

Answer (score 0):

You can check the exact error on developers console, network tab. Look there for your request and check the preview or open it in a new chrome's tab.

Posted code has a typo, maybe it is in your file too? You missed to add `$` to your `appointment` variable.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $appointment = Appointment::find($id);

    if($appointment == null) {
        return Response()->json([
            'message'=>'error delete.'
        ]);
    }

    $appointment->delete();

    return Response()->json([
        'message'=>'sucess delete.'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Probe to write _token but it was not solved, thanks for the answer

Comment: If the JS is in an external file, you cannot use Blade templating

Comment: Check the error on developers console and update your question

Comment: @aaron0207 how can I do?

Comment: @mbozwood  I've also added it to the blade and the same thing still comes out

Comment: Can you check my answer? you have a typo on your controller

Comment: @aaron0207 Thanks for your answer, I already modify it, still it is still not resolved ... I do not know what else I can do

Comment: Press Ctrl+Shift+I (Windows) or Cmd+Option+I (Mac) to open chrome dev tools, click on network tab, press the forbidden icon to clear all logged request and make a new ajax call without reload the page, now there will be  a log with your request response, click it and check the preview tab. I made a screenshot with all described tabs and elements: https://imgur.com/a/jNTIH

Comment: @aaron0207 Thanks for your time, the error is that: TokenMismatchException, in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68)